# Monopoly: Can I Buy Properties Right Before I Go To Jail?

Tags: monopoly

I rolled doubles three times in a row, and I landed on Illinois Avenue on my last roll. I want to buy it, but since it's my third double I'm going to jail. I want to buy it right now at the regular market price instead of at an auction because the other players have a ton of money and may bid very high for Illinois Avenue.

Can I buy it now? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The rules state:

> If you throw doubles three times in succession, move your token immediately to the space marked "In Jail".

So when you roll the third doubles, you go straight to Jail and never visit the space you would otherwise land on, so you don't get to purchase it.

Comment: And it doesn't to go auction for not having been purchased by the active player.

Comment: And if you would have passed go you do not pass go and thus do not collect $200. (It's not often I get to say that and it's actually in context!)

Comment: great answer, marking the fact that you dont even hit the space in question before you go to jail so no chance to buy or send to auction