# What happens if you roll doubles 3 times then land on "Go to jail?"

Tags: monopoly

Do you have to serve two jail sentences? For example, you go to jail the first time and use your "Get out of jail free" card, and then go right back to jail for another sentence without rolling the dice.

Comment: Highly related/duplicate: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/38845

Comment: Although this question has already been answered correctly, if you want to have some fun with this I suggest that it is in the scope of the rules to pretend like you didn't remember this is your third roll of doubles, start moving, then land on "go to jail" and exclaim, "OH NO! I LANDED ON GO TO JAIL!" as you move your token to the jail.  This would work especially well if some of the other players catch you on it being your third roll of doubles and are trying to explain it to you while you ignore them and move your token anyway.

Comment: @Jan I agree that these are about the same thing, but neither is a good duplicate candidate for the other.  I've tried to create a canonical question to merge the two: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/45706/9999

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You go to jail directly on rolling the third double, so there’s no opportunity to land on “go to jail”.

From the [Official Monopoly Rules (Hasbro)](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf)

> If you throw doubles, you move your token as usual, the sum of the
>   two dice, and are subject to any privileges or penalties pertaining to
>   the space on which you land. Retaining the dice, throw again and move
>   your token as before. If you throw doubles three times in succession,
>   move your token immediately to the space marked "In Jail" (see JAIL).

Comment: This answer, as well as the other answer given later on, addresses the game mechanics. It is explicitly stated in the rules that property cannot be purchased, and it sort of follows that rent cannot be collected, either. I don't think I have ever tried moving my piece according to the dice value before going to jail when rolling doubles a third time in a row.

Comment: @Iktys "and it sort of follows that rent cannot be collected" No it doesn't. That's one of the most often debunked myths.

Comment: @Joseph, I believe what Iktys meant is that if your third doubles would cause you to land on someone else’s property, the other player doesn’t get to collect that rent before you go to jail.

Comment: I mean, at the space you would have landed on with the third doubles, you don't pay rent.

Comment: There's no such thing as "the space you would have landed on with the third doubles."  When you roll the third set of doubles, you go immediately to jail.  There's no point in counting spaces to see where you "would have landed."

Comment: @Kyralessa I believe that was the point he was making. He's saying that since it doesn't say that rent is collected after the third doubles, it can be assumed that rent CANNOT be collected, thus proving that you don't land on the space at all, indicating that you don't move, you simply go to jail immediately when you roll the doubles.

Comment: @CollinB There's no rent to be collected because for rent to be collected, you have to land on someone else's property.  After the third throw of doubles, the only place you land is in jail.  It only confuses matters to talk about "the space you _would have_ landed on."  There's no such space when you roll doubles three times.  There's only the space you _do_ land on: Jail.

Comment: This same misconception is in the original question.  The original question implies that after rolling doubles three times, you could land on the Go to Jail space.  This isn't true.  Upon the third roll, you go directly to Jail.  You don't "land" anywhere except Jail.  There's no point in counting off the spaces for your third roll.  It doesn't matter how many spaces it is to the Jail; that's the only place you're going.

Comment: @Kyralessa That is...... exactly what I just said......

Comment: @CollinB You said a lot of things that don't have any relevance.  It's not necessary to reason one's way 'round from "It doesn't say rent can be collected" to "You go to jail immediately."  It could scarcely be more clear: "If you throw doubles three times in succession, move your token immediately to the space marked 'In Jail' ".  It's obvious that if you move directly to jail, then you don't land on any other space and don't take actions associated with any other space.

Comment: @Kyralessa I'll point out that it is clearly not obvious to everybody, hence this question's existence. It was someone else's separate way of reasoning that you have chosen to disagree with because it was "unnecessary," but as long as it might help the person who asked the question, I see no reason to disregard any path of logic, no matter how convoluted you may think it is.

Comment: I'll grant that the Monopoly rules do leave quite a bit of ambiguity in some cases, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 45):

You're thinking about this too much in terms of real-life prison sentences, and too little as game mechanics. "Jail" is simply a location on the board, associated with a few specific rules, but none of those rules suggest that there would be "Jail Time" stacking up. Instead, you are either in Jail, or not.

Furthermore, upon rolling doubles a third time, you are directly placed in Jail without executing your movement anyway:

> When doubles are rolled, the player resolves the roll as normal (including purchase, renting or passing "GO"), but rolls the dice again for another turn (you have to keep going). The player moves forward as directed by the dice, and if this is also doubles, rolls again. If the third dice roll is doubles, the player cannot buy property, and is instead moved directly to jail. [[source]](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Monopoly/Official_Rules#Doubles)

Comment: " "Jail" is simply a location on the board, associated with a few specific rules," Ooooooh... suddenly a lot of things regarding life and politics are more clear to me.

Comment: Where is your quotation from?

Comment: @EleventhDoctor I hadn't realized I forgot the source link - added!