# When rolling a third doubles, do you interact with the space you would land on?

Tags: monopoly

In Monopoly, when you roll doubles a third time, you go to Jail.  But do you get to interact with the space first?  More specifically, do you get to do any of the following first?

- Pass go
- [Buy property](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/38845/9999)
- Draw a Chance or Community Chest card
- Pay Luxury Tax or Income Tax
- [Gain a second "jail sentence"](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/45674/9999)
- Pay Rent

Comment: @JoeW the whole point of this question is for the duplicate relationship to go the other way.  This is intended as the cannonical question for the one linked

Comment: Zags, If you are going to create a question to be a duplicate target for another question you should also vote to close that other question as a duplicate of the question you created. It does no one any good to create a new question as a duplicate target and not following that up by voting to close the other questions.

Comment: I would also point out that the question being asked and answered 3 days ago has gotten a lot of upvotes so far so it doesn't seem like a bad question or answer.

Comment: @JoeW I marked both other questions as duplicates of this one as soon as I was able (you can't do it before the new question has upvotes).  Furthermore, the amount of attention the "go to jail" question has received is unrelated to its suitability as a canonical question on the subject.  This question is designed to be more general, and https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/38845/9999 is closed as a duplicate of this one.  https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/45674/9999 should also be closed as a duplicate of this to avoid confusion

Comment: Zags, the other question is highly upvoted and not that bad, I think you would be much better served by updating that question and answer to improve it rather then create an unneeded duplicate target to deal with two questions.

Comment: @JoeW changing that question to look like this one would be an extreme change in question intent, and I think far beyond the scope of an edit.  Meanwhile, this question alredy exists in the form that a duplicate target would need to exist.

Comment: It doesn't have to look like this one, or cover every single possibility, in order for it to be a better question.

Comment: @JoeW I agree.  However, both of the questions are sufficiently specific in what the author is asking about that neither is a good candidate for editing into a more general question on the subject.  This question covers all of the cases so that it can best serve as a general question on the subject.

Comment: @Zags Please do not include meta information about the intention of your question in the question itself. If you want it to act as a canonical question it should stand on its own merits, and the determination of how to close questions as duplicates should not depend on the intentions behind asking the questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you roll doubles a third time, you do not move to or interact with the space that the dice would take you to.  Instead you go directly to Jail.  You do not get to do any of the listed examples.

From the rules:

> If you throw doubles, you move your token as usual, the sum of the two dice, and are subject to any privileges or penalties pertaining tot he space on which you land. Retaining the dice, throw again and move your token as before. If you throw doubles three times in succession, move your token immediately to the space marked “In Jail” (see JAIL).